# Arc relationship (XOR) in Oracle SQL Sata Modeler?

Tags: oracle, relationship, foreign-key-relationship, xor, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I need to model database in Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler.

I have to create ARC relationship (XOR), but I don't know how.
I have found checkbox "In Arc" in Foreign Keys properties, but it is disable (grey). I don't see any other options, which pertain to Arc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to select the relationship lines in the diagram, and then hit the 'New Arc' button on the main toolbar.

From the help:

"To create an arc, do so after creating all the relationships to be included. Select the entity box, select all relationship lines to be included (hold Shift and click each line), and click the New Arc button in the toolbar."

[image]

Comment: I have read this instruction from help before, but your text shown me, where is the New Arc button. I missed it.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Here's a picture, if that helps [picture](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/arc_button.png)